# How to amplify Audio Data in Oboe onAudioReady Method?

Tags: android, c++, audio, oboe

I want to amplify the audioData that is recorded by microphone using Oboe Library. 
I created AudioEngine.cpp like this: https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/LiveEffect/src/main/cpp/LiveEffectEngine.cpp
Here's is the class that has audioData:

```
DataCallbackResult
AudioEngine::onAudioReady(AudioStream *oboeStream, void *audioData, int32_t numFrames) {

    /* some code */


 // add your audio processing here

    return DataCallbackResult::Continue;
}
```

Comment: I tried 0.2f instead of 2, still it's distorting heavily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the LiveEffect sample both the recording and playback streams are `AudioFormat::I16` i.e. 16 bit integers. On this line you're casting to `float`:

```
auto *outputData = static_cast<float *>(audioData);
```

This is going to cause the distortion you hear so instead just cast to `int16_t` and multiply by a constant amplitude.

Make sure to check that the scaled up sample value isn't above `INT16_MAX` otherwise you'll get wraparound and distortion.